Generalized Ohm's Law
Hi I'm here to seek help to understand something my physics professor wrote which I think is wrong. My professor started talking about the generalized Ohm's Law considering two nodes of a circuit, A and B, between which there's a generic circuit component.
Being generic, the total electric field inside this component is: $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_{es} + \vec{E}_e + \vec{E}_c$, where $\vec{E}_e$ is the electromotive field while $\vec{E}_c$ is the counter-electromotive field.
What bothers me is that he then said: $\vec{E} = \rho \vec{j}$ where $\rho$ is the resistivity of the component and $\vec{j}$ is the electric current density. The problem is this formula should be used just in the occasion the component considered is ohmic, so why did he used it in this occasion? Is it right?
Just for completeness, this discussion was made to obtain the following relation:
$$V_A - V_B + \sum_{i} f_{e,i} + \sum_{i} f_{c,i} = I R_{AB}$$
where $f_e$ is the emf, while $f_c$ is the counter-electromotive force and $R_{AB}$ is the resistance between the node A and B.


The problem is this formula should be used just in the occasion the component considered is ohmic, so why did he used it in this occasion? Is it right?

Because the "generalized Ohm's law" (actually, based on Kirchhoff's ideas) is still meant, at first, only for those elements for which the work of resistance force against DC current can be modeled by the term $RI$ (linearly proportional to current). The other generalization to non-linear elements (which does not seem to have been  your professor's point when writing those expressions), can be attempted later, e.g. by assuming $R$ depends on current or other physical circumstances (electric field, magnetic field).
The "generalized" does not mean we're considering element that does not behave ohmically for DC current; it means that the current in the element is allowed to experience not only electrostatic force due to drop of electric potential $V$, like in Ohm's law $V = RI$, but also can experience other impressed forces, such as due to electro-chemical EMF (like in a battery), or induced EMF (due to self-induction or induction due to other circuit). So then we have an equation similar to Ohm's law, where drop of potential $V$ is only part of all impressed force effects acting on the current, the other parts being electric and non-electric EMFs acting on the current:
$$
V + \sum_{m} \mathscr{E}_m = RI.
$$
When this generalized Ohm's law is summed for all elements in a closed path, the potential drop terms sum up to zero, and we get Kirchoff's second circuital law: sum of emfs acting in a closed path equals sum of terms $R_kI_k$ in the path, where $R_k$ is resistance of $k-$th element:
$$
\sum_m \mathscr{E}_m = \sum_k R_k I_k.
$$
Note that not all EMFs that can be in the equation above are due to partial electric fields; especially the electro-chemical EMF in a battery is not due to electric field, but also e.g. motional EMF in a conductor moving in magnetic field is not. So it is not correct to express net electric field $\mathbf E$ as sum of all "electromotive fields". This is because those include also the electro-chemical and motional EMF, which are not electric. The sum of all forces per unit charge (due to both electric and non-electric forces) is better denoted by other symbol, e.g. $\mathbf{E}^*$. The generalized Ohm law, in a local form, is:
$$
\mathbf{E}^* = \rho \mathbf{j}_{cond}.
$$
The same law in an integral form, for one element with terminals 1,2, is:
$$
\int_1^2 \mathbf{E}^* \cdot d\mathbf{s} = R_{1\to 2} I,
$$
or
$$
V_{1\to 2} + \sum_m \mathscr{E}_{m,1\to 2} =  R_{1\to 2} I.  
$$
And the same law, in an integral form, for a closed path $\gamma$ (Kirchhoff's second circuital law):
$$
\oint_\gamma\mathbf{E}^* \cdot d\mathbf{s} = \oint_\gamma \rho \mathbf j_{cond} \cdot d\mathbf s,
$$
or
$$
\sum_m \mathscr{E}_{m,loop} = \sum_k R_k I_k.
$$

to my knowledge, "generalized" in generalized Ohm's law means that it applies to nonlinear resistive materials. In a generalized resistor, capacitor, inductor we have v=R(i) i, i=C(v)v', v=L(i)i'. See for example Chua, Desoer, Kuh, "Linear and nonlinear circuits"or the previous version "Basic Circuit Theory"by Desoer and Kuh.

@Peltio That's the different generalization, which came later, and does not seem to be the concern of the derivation described in OP. The first generalization, due to Kirchoff, was about including other forces than the electrostatic force, and thus getting additional terms in the equation which relates $RI$ to forces acting on current.

It makes sense (even tho I do not agree with your point on view on which electric field to use)

@Peltio what do you not agree on, and why?

@JánLalinský I'm probably misunderstanding something. If I know that inside of a component, the total electric field is schemed as $\vec{E} = \vec{E}{s} + \vec{E}{e} + \vec{E}_{c}$ doesn't necessarily mean that the component is non-ohmic because of the fact that current and voltage cannot be directly proportional because of electromotive and counter-electromotive fields happening in the component?

@deomanu01 The formula for electric field is probably what is misleading you, so I suggest you ignore it for a while. The actual generalized Ohm's law is that in element made of ohmic conductor, current is proportional to sum of all impressed forces (electric and non-electric, acting on the current) integrated over the current path. This includes potential difference(electric), induced emf(sometimes called back-emf, or counter-emf, electric), electro-chemical emf (non-electric), motional emf(non-electric in the frame of magnetic field source), and any other emf.

@deomanu01 In the formula you wrote, $\vec{E}_e$ is suggested to be a part of net electric field. This is true if $\vec{E}_e$ refers to induced electric field, but induced electric field seems to be there with another index, so I assume the professor meant that $\vec{E}_e$ is e.g. impressed force due to a battery or thermocouple. Then, however, the formula is wrong, because in macroscopic theory, battery EMF or thermoelectric EMF is not due to electric field. But the rest is fine if you interpret $\vec{E}$ as sum of all impressed forces per unit charge, not as electric field.

@deomanu01 You are right that when induced electric field has substantial effect on current in a component, such as in an inductor, then the component is not an ohmic component. At the same time, the material the inductor coils are made of (copper) is often called ohmic conductor, because the modern local Ohm's law $\mathbf E = \rho \mathbf j$ is valid in copper, even when part of inductor, even though the simple Ohm's law for the component $V=RI$ does not hold. So one can have non-ohmic element (inductor) made of ohmic conductor medium (copper).

It's fine to use ⃗ = ⃗ for a non-ohmic, isotropic material, as long as you realise that $\rho$ is, in this case, not a constant, but depends on the magnitude, $E$, of the field strength.
I don't really understand your ⃗ = ⃗ + ⃗ + ⃗, but that's beside the point!

Thank you for pointing that out. But how do you derive mathematically the equation $\vec{E} = \rho \vec{j}$ when this is originally based on the assumption that $\Delta V = R I$? The sum of those fields is because inside a component, there could be an emf, a counter electromotive force and an electrostatic field, so $\vec{E}$ is the result of the vector sum of all the possible fields, if I understood that correctly.
EDIT: For non-ohmic materials, $\vec{E} = \rho \vec{j}$ becomes a local relation?

But how do you derive mathematically the equation ⃗=⃗ when this is originally based on the assumption that Δ= ? Δ= can be applied to  a non-ohmic conductor, as long as you realise that in this case $R$ is not a constant, but depends on $V$! Δ= is, imo, best regarded as a definition of resistance, $R$. If the conductor obeys Ohm's law, $R$ is constant; if not, it isn't.

"For non-ohmic materials, ⃗=⃗ becomes a local relation?" Yes; one can imagine a conductor whose cross-sectional area varies along its length. When a pd is applied across its ends and there is a current, $j$ will be greater in the narrower bits, so $\rho$ will be different here from what it is in the wider bits, if the conducting material is non-ohmic.

Maxwell's equations on the quantities $\rho, \mathbf {J,E,H,B,D}$ on the 1 scalar+20 field quantities (vector components) are partial differential equations connecting different fields, (here by $\rho$ I mean charge density). That connection is not complete, and you must augment them with appropriate boundary conditions and with constitutive relationships that define the material within which they act.
A generalized "Ohmic" conductor is just a functional relationship between current and electric field. In lumped element circuits a resistor is a linear relationship between the current through its terminals and the voltage drop between its terminals: $V=IR$ and $R$ is to be a material constant, you may just as well say that this is a definition of a particular 2-terminal device.
A more complicated example is an ideal Shockley diode, also a 2-terminal device, a functional relationship between current through it and voltage between its terminals given by $I=I_{sat}(e^{V/V_T}-1)$ that is an exponentially growing monotonic function.
A non-monotonic example of an I=f(V) relationship is the tunnel diode, and there are other more complicated examples, too. These lumped circuit element examples have obvious field generalization where the spatially varying relationship is between the current density and electric field intensity, say, $\mathbf {F(J, E)=0}.$ The current could even depend not only on the voltage (electric field) but also on an external magnetic bias field, see the Hall effect. Memory and thermal effects can also be introduced in the constitutive relationship, see the various electrolytic battery models. The same could be said about $\rho, \mathbf D$ involving "capapitors" and the other field quantities.
These are not "laws" in the sense of Maxwell's equations but constitutive relationships. An analogy from other parts of physics would be the conservation of the sum of kinetic and potential energies in mechanics, written as $\frac{dE}{dt}=0,$ for a weightless spring loaded with a point mass written as $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ where the constitutive relationship $F=-kx$ is the relationship that defines what an ideal spring is, from which the potential energy of the point mass $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ follows. If the spring is not of a "linear response" type then it could have a much more complicated form $F=-kx+ax^3+...$, and then the potential energy is $\frac{1}{2}kx^2-\frac{1}{4}ax^4.$
